# Storing the output of all commands of expect script

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm a bit new to TCL scripting.I have  written a expect shell script where in I have multiple expect-send commands.

I came to know that expect_out(buffer) stores only the output of previous command.However my goal is to store the output of all comannds used in script.

How do I that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$expect_out(buffer)` for every command as shown below:

```
send "show interface\r"  ; # 1st command
expect "*#"
set a $expect_out(buffer)
send "show vlan\r"  ; # 2nd command
expect "*#"
set b $expect_out(buffer)
send "show ip interface brief\r"  ; # 3rd command
expect "*#"
set c $expect_out(buffer)
```

Here you can see all the command outputs captured to the respective variables.

```
puts $a
puts $b
puts $c
```

Comment: Hey thanks, that works !! Also could you provide an example on how to use $expect(0,string) or $expect(1,string) and so on...

Comment: Expect stores the matched characters in `expect_out(0,string)`. For `exepect(1, string)`, `expect(2, string)`, and so on, they are used to store string matching subpattern. This is useful when you have regular expression in your scripts.